# Why does using auto and int give different answers in this code?

Tags: c++, c++11

I am assigning 2 variables the values of 10. When i use ref() on one of those variables using "int", i get a different value and when i use "auto", i get a different value.

```
Using auto

     int foo(10);
     auto bar = std::ref(foo);
     ++bar; 
     cout << foo << endl;
     std::cout << bar << endl << endl;

Output: 11
        11
```

```
Using int

     int boo(10);
     int jar;
     jar = std::ref(boo);
     ++jar;
     std::cout << boo << '\n';
     std::cout << jar << '\n';

Output: 10 (why does this not increment?)
        11
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The utility [std::ref](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) returns an object of type [std::reference_wrapper](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper).

Therefore, in your example:

```
auto bar = std::ref(foo);
```

The type of `bar` will exactly be `std::reference_wrapper`. In short, it will behave as a *reference*, so the effect of the statement `++bar;` will increase the value of the referenced variable (i.e., `foo`).

On the other hand, in the statement:

```
int jar = std::ref(boo);
```

`jar` as type `int`. **Note**: that is *not* a reference, rather a completely new variable named `jar`. When you increment `jar`, that won't affect the other variable (`foo`).

---

**Additional Notes**:

For sake of completeness, the statement `int jar = std::ref(boo);` hides an implicit cast. Indeed, the object `std::reference_wrapper` can be implicitly casted into a `T&`.

Answer (score 2):

The [`std::ref`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref) function creates a [`std::reference_wrapper`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/reference_wrapper) object. This object wraps a reference to `foo`.

With

```
auto bar = std::ref(foo);
```

you basically creates (in an indirect way) a reference to `foo`, and in that first example all modifications to `bar` will be made to `foo`. It's equivalent to

```
std::reference_wrapper<int> bar = std::ref(foo);
```

and behaves basically like a plain reference:

```
int& bar = foo;
```

In the second example you also create such a reference wrapper object, but then you take its value and copy it into the variable `jar`. The reference wrapper object is then destructed. All modifications to `jar` are only done to the variable `jar` itself, not to `foo`.

Comment: is that because of auto? Because the concept being used is the same right?